# Bootstrap 3 Panel Header with Buttons Set to Not Respect Parent Padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theobliviouskid/zk1c6zo9/) to demonstrate what I have now:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Panel Title</h4>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button A</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button B</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button C</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Normal Bootstrap 3 Panel Header with Buttons]

What I want to happen is for the **buttons** to have the full-height of the panel (such that there is **no space, top and bottom**) and to have it move to the edge (such that there is **no space on the right side**).

I'm thinking of using negative margins and setting the height of the buttons, but that seems hacky? Is there no better way, a class, maybe, that I can use?

Comment: Where is the fiddle?

Comment: Updated post. Fixed the link.

Comment: Thanks, having a bit of trouble trying to figure out what exactly you want to-do. If you give 100% height to the btn-group and 100% height to the btn-default then it should change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df5t423L/2/)

There is a padding on the panel-heading that you need to remove.

```
.option-button {
    height:100%;
}

.media-object {
    height: 50;
}
.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
    }

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">Panel Title</h4>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right media-object">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default option-button">Button A</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default option-button">Button B</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default option-button">Button C</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess so. I would have preferred if I didn't have to remove the padding but this does the job.

Comment: If you want the padding still you will need to set negative margins